# GWT application fails only when inside iframe in IE 8/9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gwt

I have a GWT application that is supposed to be embedded in a customer's website via iframe.

In MSIE 9 and below, I get "Exception thrown and not caught," and the iframe is empty.

URL to page with broken iframe:
http://vuecaremedia.com/test-embedded/single.html

URL to iframe contents itself, which works:
http://licensing.vuecaremedia.com/portal/?embed=32afc25c-e821-4c03-933c-d8b38c349eb1&video=8

If I use the IE dev tools and change Document Mode to Internet Explorer 9 Standards, it works!
But these all fail:

Quirks Mode

Internet Explorer 7 Standards

Internet Explorer 8 Standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IE both the container page and the iframe one should use the same `doctype` otherwise the iframe inherits the doctype of its parent.

So you have to ask your customer to include this in their hosted page:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue isn't with the frame itself but rather with the video plugin you are using. JW Player has been noted to have some strange behavior in IE7 and IE8 especially when using older versions of Flash.

I'm not an expert with the JW Player, but you may want to post the issue to http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player. I've tried using the URL by using quirks mode and it is not working.

And, the video page at http://licensing.vuecaremedia.com/portal/?embed=32afc25c-e821-4c03-933c-d8b38c349eb1&video=8 actually states that Quirks mode is not supported:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->
```